# Bootstrap Slider ... Min and Max ... Change Separator

Tags: bootstrap-slider

It would be great if you could help me with a problem.

I'm using Bootstrap Slider (https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/).

I want to display the Current Slider Value.

It works with the comma. How can I change the ',' -> ' to '

```html
Age Range ...<br/>
<b>18</b> &nbsp; &nbsp;  <span><input id="ex2" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="18" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[30,55]"/></span> &nbsp; &nbsp; <b>100</b><br/>
<span id="ageSliderLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ageSliderVal">30,55</span></span>


 <!-- Bootstrap Slider -->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.2.1/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.2.1/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>  
 
 <script>
  var slider = new Slider('#ex2', {});
  slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
   document.getElementById("ageSliderVal").textContent = sliderValue; 
  });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("ageSliderVal").textContent = sliderValue.replace(",", " to ")
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does not work for me.

I have to integrate the code with backslash in php and then nothing works anymore.

> var slider = new Slider('#ex2', {});
>           slider.on(\"slide\", function(sliderValue) {
>               document.getElementById(\"ageSliderVal\").textContent = sliderValue.replace(\",\", \" to \")
>           });

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution.

It works after using toString()

```
    <script>
    var slider = new Slider('#ex2', {});
    slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
        var sliderValue = sliderValue.toString();
        document.getElementById("ageSliderVal").textContent = sliderValue.replace(",", " to ")
    });     
</script>
```